# How to tile multiple GeoTIFFs exported from Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, tiles, gdal2tiles

When exporting large raster datasets from Google Earth Engine, the data is broken up into many GeoTIFFs. What is the best way to create map tiles from these? I have a couple of concerns in regards to this:

- "Large" tiles / low zoom levels: The GeoTIFFs cover less area than low zoom level map tiles. So they would individually only take up a portion of these tiles, leaving the remaining space blank where there should be data from the adjacent TIFF.
- GeoTIFFs overlap: I am unsure if the TIFFs overlap or if they each cover adjacent regions like I would expect them to. If they overlap, I worry tiling them individually will produce duplicates of incomplete tiles.

I am very new to GIS. I've only ever tiled using [gdal2tiles](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal2tiles.html), and it doesn't seem capable of tiling multiple GeoTIFFs at once. I don't know how to combine them into one file, or if this is even possible (or necessary). Is there another tool (like QGIS) that can tile *multiple* GeoTIFFs? Or could at least combine them somehow?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`gdalbuildvrt`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalbuildvrt.html) (or the QGIS [Build Virtual Raster](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rastermiscellaneous.html#build-virtual-raster) tool which uses `gdalbuildvrt`) to combine the the GeoTIFFs into a single mosaiced output.  You can then can generate your map tiles from that.  I can't provide any more specific instructions as or address your concerns as you have provided any details about the exported GeoTIFFs.

`gdalbuildvrt` will output a [VRT](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/vrt.html) which is just an XML text file that describes how to combine the underlying GeoTIFFs, but don't worry about that, `gdal2tiles` will just treat it as a single raster.

The advantage of using `gdalbuildvrt` is that the output VRT doesn't take up much disk space whereas something like `gdal_merge` will output a new raster.

Comment: I appreciate your response! I will give this a try soon and accept your answer if it worked. So I assume I can then just treat this as if it's a regular GeoTIFF (i.e. `gdal2tiles.py --zoom=3-14 --xyz combined-tiffs.vrt output-dir`). One follow up question: do you prefer QGIS or working with the GDAL library directly?

Comment: Yes `gdal2tiles.py --zoom=3-14 --xyz combined-tiffs.vrt output-dir`. `gdal2tiles` will just treat combined-tiffs.vrt as a single raster.  I don't have a preference, depends on what I'm doing.

Comment: in theory, it should as vrt is acts like C++ pointer to the actual data